# Have the new bounty changes caused more bounties to appear?

Tags: discussion, bounties, statistics

With the new bounty changes have more bounties appeared? Can anyone experienced with OData etc tell me?

Is this a good thing? Why do you think the bounties have increased(if they have) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Improvements to the Bounty System](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) just rolled out in June, so it's too early to tell from the data dump.

I created the [Bounties Awarded by Month](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/356/bounties-awarded-by-month) query on SEDE so we can watch and see what impact the changes have in the coming months though.  I'll be interested to see what happens in the first couple of months after the changes and in the long term.  Great question!

#### Update:

[@shahkalpesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23574/shahkalpesh) was able to help me combine my queries (see the comments below) to add the total number of questions asked in each month, so now we can track that along with the bounties in [Bounties and Questions by Month](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/358/bounties-and-questions-by-month).

Comment: Hmm... Can you normalize that by the number of questions asked each month?

Comment: @mmyers: That's a good idea, but it's a bit beyond my meager SQL skills.  I've written another script that shows the [Questions Asked by Month](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/357/questions-asked-by-month), but I don't know an easy way to combine them.

Comment: Luckily, I happen to know of [a web site where I can ask for help with such things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287145/help-me-combine-these-two-queries).

Comment: Looks good. I added a percentage column: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/7767/bounties-and-questions-by-month.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, without a doubt, it has.

I haven't had time to run queries, but I've noticed an increase... which was definitely part of the intent. Bounties were underused, partly because the system was too inflexible, but also because people are oddly hesitant to sacrifice *any* rep.

Comment: They are hesitant because rep is the closest thing to a currency we have here - and our subconsciousness associates a value to it because we had to work for deserving it. And since a question might be well answered without setting a bounty this seems like a bit of gambling - you may even gain rep because of up-votes due to the increased prominence of your question...

Comment: @tobias yes it is explicitly gambling! I am just surprised folks are so conservative with this synthetic currency. Much more than I would have expected.

Comment: I wasn't concerned with the rep so much as having an answer accepted for me that I can't change and that I can't apply a bounty again

Comment: Most of us earn real currency just for showing up at work every day. Earning rep is actually more difficult :)

Comment: Atwood♦: synthetic or not, it represents appreciation for work you did by useful contributions (you might possibly even calculate an entropy disposal equivalent...) and some people equate rep = fame. Which, on the other hand, may also explain the success of bounties